# Get list iterator index

Tags: c++, list, iterator, binary-search

I have a sorted `list<int>` and I will add an element inside it, at an index such that the list will keep sorted:

```
list<int> l;
list<int>::iterator upper;

for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) l.push_back(i);

int x = 15;

upper = upper_bound (l.begin(), l.end(), x);
l.insert(up, aux);

cout<<"Added "<<x<<" at index "<<(upper - l.begin())<<endl;
```

The iterator difference done in the `cout` doesn't work for lists, so how can I find this index fast?

Ignoring the `for`, I want this full operation to be O(lg(n)), which is the time of a binary search.

If I could retrive this index in constant time, it would be great. Using `vector` is not an option.

Comment: How are you going to do a binary search in O(lg(n)) on a linked list?

Comment: It is strange indeed, but the upper_bound is working.

Comment: It is working, just not in O(lg(n)). It takes O(n).

Comment: Have you considered using a binary tree?

Comment: It makes no sense in my environment. Anyway, is there a way to get the upper_bound index?

Comment: Sure, just do a linear search over `l` until you reach `upper`. It won't make the time complexity any worse.

Comment: I guess `upper_bound` is checking type internally and then decides if want to perform binary search or linear search

Comment: but there is no point to use `upper_bound ` for list to get index

Comment: @Mayur I'm pretty sure it just calls `std::advance` internally, which for random access iterators is just an increment, but for lists is a loop.

Comment: I had this feeling... thanks for clearing things up!

Comment: I am not sure, but need to check `std::distance` may be work in this case

Comment: @Mayur same problem. Linked lists are not linear in memory. The only way to calculate the "distance" between two linked list nodes is to start at one node and iterate through the list one node at a time in order until you reach the other node.

Comment: I was expecting the same from `std::distance` but it does not work that way.